# Visual studio core no conecta a SQLserver 2008 SP1 en linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, vscode, fedora

Tengo una BBDD sql server funcionando y con conectividad, he instalado visual studio core y he tratado de conectar a la BBDD sin éxito.

He comprobado lo siguiente:

1. hay conexión a la BBDD me puedo conectar desde DBveaver y desde python sin problemas desde varios pcs incluido desde el que me quiero conectar y alguna VM
2. El usuario y contraseña son correctos
3. La ip es correcta, he intentado también hacerlo por nombre de hosts
4. La BBDD no esta bloqueada, por otros metodos funciona perfectamente
5. Al configurar la BBDD en visual studio y darle a "probar conexión" me da todo bien

He probado con las extensiones:
SQLtools 0.23.0 con el driver versión 0.2.0
SQL server(mssql) 1.9.0

EL SO es fedora 32

el servidor sql es Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64) (y no se puede actualizar)

Al parecer es un problema con TLS según lo que he logrado encontrar y todas las soluciones hablan de actualizar el SQL server cosa que no es posible

¿alguna sugerencia?

el error que me da:

> mssql: Failed to connect: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the
> server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.
> (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. --->
> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error
>
> - SSL_ERROR_SSL. ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported
>   protocol    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, Byte[] recvBuf,
>   Int32 recvOffset, Int32 recvCount, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)
>   at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials
>   credential, SafeDeleteContext& context, SecurityBuffer inputBuffer,
>   SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions
>   sslAuthenticationOptions)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo
>   exception)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions
>   sslClientAuthenticationOptions)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost,
>   X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols
>   enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost)
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<TryGetConnection>b__1(Task`1
>   _)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&
>   currentTaskSlot)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ReliableConnection.ReliableSqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ManagedBatchParser\ReliableConnection\ReliableSqlConnection.cs:line
>   314
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ConnectionService.TryOpenConnection(ConnectionInfo
>   connectionInfo, ConnectParams connectionParams) in
>   D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\Connection\ConnectionService.cs:line
>   524 ClientConnectionId:d4798651-a241-4ed5-a9c5-ebbb7407fcfa

Comment: Pues puede que no sea cosa de actualizar MSSQL todo, pero sí hay que aplicarle las actualizaciones correspondientes (como [esta](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/3135244/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)?) para que soporte versiones seguras de protocolos TLS.

Comment: lo mas habitual sería actualizar, pero es un ordenador situado donde cristo perdio el gorro  que nadie toca por si se estropea, ya actualizaron otro igual y dejo de funcionar el programa que lleva, así que no, actualizar no es una opción, la seguridad esta garantizada ya que no tiene conexión a internet y cualquiera con acceso fisico al pc tiene una preciosa pegatina con el usuario y la contraseña, si puede acceder al ordenador como si todo va sin cifrar....

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que el error es justificado. No se debe usar ya TLS anterior a 1.2 porque se considera inseguro.

Hay un ajuste que yo no he probado, no sé si funcione pero podrías probar (asegurándote de hacer copia de seguridad del registro de windows) y está [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214002/236345). Esencialmente activa los protocolos TLS 1.1 y 1.2 en el servidor.

1. Backup del registry
2. Abrir el Editor del registry con `regedit` y navegar a esta ubicación:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols

3. Añadir las llaves `TLS 1.1` y `TLS 1.2` bajo `Protocols`. Se verán como directorios.
4. Crear ahora dos claves `Client` y `Server` bajo ambas claves `TLS 1.1` y `TLS 1.2`.
5. Crear los valores `DWORD` bajo `Server` y `Client` de `TLS 1.1` como sigue:

   ```
    DisabledByDefault [Value = 0]
    Enabled [Value = 0]
   ```
6. Crear los valores `DWORD` bajo `Server` y `Client` de `TLS 1.2` como sigue:

   ```
    DisabledByDefault [Value = 0]
    Enabled [Value = 1]
   ```

[image]
7. Reiniciar el servidor

(Yo aprovecharía y veríá si puedo deshabilitar protocolos inseguros como ese SSL 2.0 que sale en la imagen, le pondría enabled en 0.)

Comment: por si acaso (tienes mas información en otro comentario que he hecho arriba) no se toca nada de la configuración del servidor, hay programas muy antiguos que si se toca algo pueden dejar de funcionar, el día que el pc se estropee, a maquina virtual y todo igual que esta

Comment: @Durgeoble pues, el trabajo de uno no es dejar todo como está sino hacer que funcione :)

Comment: el caso es que "funciona" lo que yo quiero es poder conectar a esa BBDD con el visual studio, no es que no funcione